# Usar "->" ou "." em uma lista encadeada?

Tags: c, ponteiro, matriz, estrutura-de-dados, hash

Boa tarde, fazendo uma tabela hash sem colisões, eu criei a struct lista, porém ao compilar o código ele não aceita que eu utilize o ->prox da minha struct, ele pede que eu utilize .prox. Mas se prox é um ponteiro eu não deveria usar structlista->prox ?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define N 7
/* Lista para o tratamento das colisões (encadeamento separado) */
struct lista
{
    int info;
    /* dado */
    struct lista* prox; /* ponteiro para o próximo elemento */
};
typedef struct lista Lista;
/* Estrutura da tabela hash */
struct hash
{
    Lista **tab; /* vetor com as listas da tabela hash */
    int tam;
    /* tamanho da tabela hash */
};

typedef struct hash Hash;

int codigo_hash(int chave)
{
    return chave % N;
}

void imprime_menu(){
    printf("\n(1) Para inserir elemento\n");
    printf("(2) Para buscar elemento\n");
    printf("(3) Para imprimir a tabela\n");
    printf("(4) Para encerrar\n");
}
/*Encontra_linha:
A função vai na coluna do inteiro posicao e retorna qual deve ser o local que o
novo elemento deve ser adicionado para evitar conflitos
*/
int encontra_linha(Lista* *tabela, int posicao){
    int i;
    for(i = 0; tabela[posicao][i]->prox != NULL; i++){

    }
    return i;


}


int main()
{
    Hash hash;//cria struct do hash
    hash.tam = N;//tamanho do hash = 7
    Lista* *tabela = (Lista**) malloc (hash.tam*sizeof(Lista*));//alocando memoria da coluna da matriz
    int i,j;
    for(i=0 ; i < hash.tam; i++){//criando a linha 1 da matriz, composta apenas com NULL. Esta é a tabela hash
        tabela[i] = (Lista*) malloc(sizeof(Lista));
        tabela[i][0].info = NULL;
        tabela[i][0]->prox = NULL;
    }

    int opcao, dado, posicao, linha;
    for(;;){
    imprime_menu();
    scanf("%d", &opcao);
    switch(opcao){
        case 1:
            printf("Escreva o elemento a ser adicionado:\n");
            scanf("%d", &dado);
            posicao = codigo_hash(dado);
            linha = encontra_linha( tabela, posicao);
            tabela[posicao][linha].info = dado;
            tabela[posicao][linha]->prox = NULL;
            tabela[posicao][linha-1]->prox = tabela[posicao][linha];

            break;
        case 2:
            break;
        case 3:
            for(i=0 ;i < hash.tam; i++){
                printf("\n");
                for(j = 0; tabela[posicao][j]->prox != NULL; j++)
                    printf("%d ", tabela[i][j].info);
            }
            break;
        case 4:
            return 0;
    }
    }


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Na verdade o "struct->" é uma forma mais legível de escrever "(*struct).", que no final tem o mesmo intuito de acessar um atributo do ponteiro para struct, mas você já referenciou seu ponteiro como uma matriz "struct[][]" isso torna um erro usar a "->" para acessar os atributos da struct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pela descrição da sua pergunta parece-me que se refere a isto:

```
Lista* *tabela = (Lista**) malloc (hash.tam*sizeof(Lista*));
...

tabela[i][0].info = NULL;
//       ---^
tabela[i][0]->prox = NULL;
//       ---^
```

Que certamente não está certo. Você está a confundir os conceitos.

### Percebendo `.` vs `->`

Começo por dizer algo importante que é `->` é uma abreviação sintática. Olhemos primeiro para um caso simples.

```
struct pessoa {
    int idade;
};

struct pessoa p1;
struct pessoa *ptr1 = malloc sizeof(struct pessoa);
```

Neste cenário temos um objeto `p1` do tipo `struct pessoa` e um ponteiro `ptr1` para o tipo pessoa. Para definir a `idade` de `p1` faço `.` pois tenho o objeto diretamente:

```
p1.idade = 25;
```

No caso do ponteiro `ptr1` não posso fazer o mesmo pois tenho um ponteiro para o objeto. Logo tenho de primeiro aceder onde o ponteiro aponta com `*` e depois ao campo que interessa:

```
(*ptr1).idade = 25;
```

Como isto é chato de fazer nós temos uma abreviação sintatica que podemos usar o `->`, que corresponde ao mesmo:

```
ptr1->idade = 25;
```

Note que a **`->` não está relacionada com o tipo do campo mas sim com o tipo da variável. Se eu parto do ponteiro uso `->`, mas se parto do objeto uso `.`**

O tipo do campo afeta o valor que colocamos. Imagine agora que pessoa tem um amigo, que é um ponteiro:

```
struct pessoa {
    int idade;
    struct pessoa *amigo;
};
```

Agora para o atribuir o amigo tanto com objeto como ponteiro:

```
struct pessoa p1;
struct pessoa p2;
struct pessoa *ptr1 = malloc sizeof(struct pessoa);

p1.amigo = &p2;
ptr1->amigo = &p2;
```

### Voltando ao código da pergunta

Voltando ao seu exemplo, você tem um `Lista**`, um array de duas dimensões. Então ao fazer `[i][0]` acede a um elemento do tipo `Lista`, logo tem de usar `.` e não `->`, pois `Lista` não é um ponteiro.

Se tivesse um `Lista***` teria um array de duas dimensões de ponteiros, então ai ao fazer `[i][0]` ficaria com algo do tipo `Lista*` que é um ponteiro, e poderia então usar `->` (não que fizesse sentido no seu código).